# Springs @MockBean is not always used

Tags: java, spring, mocking, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to test if my spring boot application correctly receives messages from an AWS SQS queue by using spring clouds aws messaging.

Listener:

```
@Component
public class RequestListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestListener.class);

    private final MyService myService;

    public RequestListener(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @SqsListener(value = "${aws.queue.url}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ALWAYS)
    void getRequest(MyRequest request) {
        LOG.info("Fetched new message from SQS: {}", request);
        myService.processRequest(request);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(SpringProfiles.TEST)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class TestClass {

...

@MockBean
MyService myService;

@Test
void testReceiveMessage() {
    var payload = MyRequest.builder().content("foo").build();
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(testQueueUrl, payload);

    when(myService.processRequest(payload)).thenReturn(true);
    verify(myService, Mockito.timeout(2000).atLeastOnce()).processRequest(payload);
}
...
```

The message is received everytime (I see the log) but there's a 50% chance that the verify will fail as the Mock is never called (Error: zero interactions). I first thought this might be some synchronization issue (thus the timeout) but I can actually see that the real `MyService` service is called and not the Mock whenever the test fails.

I run the tests using `mvn clean install`

So my question is, how is it possible that randomly somtimes the Mock and sometimes the real object is called?

I also tried deactivating the real service with a custom `@Profile` annotation for the test but that didn't change the behaviour either.

Tested with Boot-Version 2.3.9.RELEASE and spring cloud HOXTON.SR10
(and also with Boot-Version 2.4.1 and cloud version HOXTON.SR10)

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Do you have more `@SpringBootTest` annotated classes with different profiles, `@MockBean` instances etc.?

Comment: They all have the "test" profile and this is the only test that mocks this service (or uses @MockBean at all, it's a rather newish project)

Comment: Which means, when running all the tests, you will end up with 2 listeners. Depending on your configuration the delivery to those will be round-robin (as there are now 2 listeners for the same queue). You will get a new context due to the `@MockBean`.

Comment: Yes! To try it out I only activated the listener for a new test profile which my test uses and it seems to consistently work now. Do you know how I could ensure that there is only one listener for this test in a clean way? Thank you anyways! If you want to rewrite it as an answer I would accept it :)

Comment: Thinking about it, wouldn't that problem always occur as soon as any test creates a new context? So also other tests that involve the queue in any way might be affected as I never know in which context the message ends up..

Comment: I have  to correct myself there is a second test that uses @MockBean which might be the issue

Comment: Only tests that require the creation of a new context instead of being able to reuse an existing one. The test context framework caches contexts based on certain keys if they are the same it will reuse an existing one.